# Using external pdfviewer when the pdf name is changed using -job-name

Tags: pdf, texmaker, viewers, jobname, sumatrapdf

I am using TexMaker and SumatraPDF for a viewer. Everything works fine. I then wanted to change the pdf name when compiling using the following command:

```
%& -job-name=SLR-Review
```

This placed on top works and creates a completely new pdf. THe issue however is that, the view now shows an old file in pdfviewer and does not update it continously. Further the file is the old filename and not the new.

Is there any way of accommodating this issue, to make the external pdf viewer show the changed output file?

Or should I simply only use the method `%& -job-name=SLR-Review` when the document is finished (kind of defeats the purpose of using the method)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with TeXmaker, but most editors like that have a settings window that specifies the command-line call to the viewer with all kinds of options and possible variables. Usually these variables are variations on the source `.tex` filename/path or a project's "main file" name/path, so it might not be possible to use `\jobname` in this command string.

Comment: By the way: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: To which end are you renaming the PDF?

Comment: @PaulGessler Thx! I have tried introducing it in the build options, but could not get it to work. So you might be right in `jobname` not existing. But I would not rule it out with my limited knowledge on TexMaker :)

Comment: @KeksDose I am renaming the pdf to have different outputs, and I want to look at the latest one. It is just because I am lazy in not renaming and copying around. But it would save me time, so therefore I am looking for the solution

Comment: In my editor (winedt) it would be imho possible to record --jobname and use this to open the file. I have been thinking a bit about this but it isn't easy to design a sensible workflow, even more as I'm often compiling more than one document. So I avoid --jobname if possible and use wrapper files if I want different outputs from one document.